# Can I degrade PLA into something usable?

Tags: plastics, hydrolysis, enzymes

I have a lot of 3D printer waste and don't have a recycling machine for it.

As a side project, I was wondering if there is any way to degrade/compost/recycle it meaningfully.
I have my Uni's chemistry lab available to me so I could play around with a lot of things.

I am only an amateur chemist, but the teacher likes me and is interested in the project too.

And just for fun, if we could make something out of it like glucose or alcohol or something, I read you can do that with organic molecules, that would be double the fun.

I will add some papers I have found:

1. http://greensxm.com/composting-pla-plastic/
2. [https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/pen.25511#:~:text=4.4%20Enzymatic%20degradation,lipase%2C%20esterase%2C%20and%20alcalase](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/pen.25511#:%7E:text=4.4%20Enzymatic%20degradation,lipase%2C%20esterase%2C%20and%20alcalase).
3. https://sci-hub.st/10.1007/s12010-010-9117-7